# Picking random entries from mongodb using spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to fetch x random entries from mongodb using spring.

My repository looks as follows

```
public interface StoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Story, Long> {
    @Query("{$sample: {size: ?0} }")
    List<Story> findRandom(int quantity);
}
```

And the error I'm getting looks like this

```
com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.domain.Example
```

I've also tried the following which gives exactly the same error

```
    public List<Story> findRandom(final int quantity) {
        CustomAggregationOperation customAggregationOperation = new CustomAggregationOperation(new BasicDBObject("$sample", new BasicDBObject("size", quantity)));
        TypedAggregation<Story> aggregation = new TypedAggregation<>(Story.class, customAggregationOperation);
        AggregationResults<Story> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Story.class);
        return aggregationResults.getMappedResults();
    }
```

My story class looks as follows

```
public class Story {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String by;
    private int descendants;
    private List<Long> kids;
    private int score;
    private long time;
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private String url;

    private By author;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ...
}
```

And my pom files as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>dk.tons.hackernews.backend</groupId>
<artifactId>tons-hackernews-backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Backend</name>
<description>Tons Hacker News Backend</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Is `Example` a subclass of `Story`?

Comment: Nope, I have no clue what it is... I'm not using it.

Comment: Please post your `Story` class and your POM/Gradle file.

Comment: Done... Stackoverflow is forcing me to write more than done...

Comment: Is your `Story` class annotated with `@Document`? Do you have `@EnableMongoRepositories` anywhere?

Comment: (Note that from personal experience MongoDB is a poor choice for models like this where you have lots of relationships between data objects: You have to do all your joins by hand.)

Comment: I've added \@Document and \@EnableMongoRepositories which didn't make a difference. There will be no joins... it's only for caching.

Comment: I know you said you don't know where Example comes from, but still, you should do a "full search, through all files" for the word "example", non-case sentitive. Just make sure you live no rock unturned. Otherwise, your implementation with CustomAggregationOperation seems good.

Comment: I appreciate your support. I did a full text search and there isn't a single occurrence of the word "Example". I've updated the question with a link to the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why it fails

You used a custom query `@Query("{$sample: {size: ?0} }")` and/or defined your `CustomAggregationOperation` like this (using `context.getMappedObject`):

```
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;
    public CustomAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(final AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Both go through `QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword`, which is the spring method that raises the error. If you open spring's `QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword`, you'll see :

```
protected DBObject getMappedKeyword(Keyword keyword, MongoPersistentEntity<?> entity) {
    ...
    if (keyword.isSample()) {
        return exampleMapper.getMappedExample(keyword.<Example<?>> getValue(), entity);
    }
    ...
}

public boolean isSample() {
    return "$sample".equalsIgnoreCase(key);
}
```

**It parses the queries and tries to use `Example` when it finds the word `$sample`.** That explains your error.

Now the question would be : how to achieve what you want without `$sample` or go around this piece of logic?  Also, an improvement request was made on Spring's JIRA, which would confirm that $sample isn't supported out of the box: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1415

## (1) Implement a CustomSampleOperation without using AggregationOperationContext

Return the $sample query without using the context:

```
CustomSampleOperation customSampleOperation = new CustomSampleOperation(1);
TypedAggregation<Story> typedAggr = Aggregation.newAggregation(Story.class, 
    customSampleperation);

AggregationResults<Story> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(typedAggr, Story.class);
aggregationResults.getMappedResults().get(0);
```

...

```
public class CustomSampleOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private int size;
    public CustomSampleOperation(int size){
        this.size = size;   
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(final AggregationOperationContext context){
        return new BasicDBObject("$sample", new BasicDBObject("size", size));
    }
}
```

If you look at how other Operations are written, we're right on ([LimitOperation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/LimitOperation.java)):

```
public class LimitOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private final long maxElements;
    public LimitOperation(long maxElements) {
        this.maxElements = maxElements;
    }

    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {    
        return new BasicDBObject("$limit", maxElements);
    }
}
```

## (2) Make it generic if you want

To keep your CustomOperation generic, you could define it like this:

```
CustomGenericOperation customGenericOperation = 
    new CustomGenericOperation(new BasicDBObject("$sample", new BasicDBObject("size", 1)));    
...

public class CustomGenericOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject dbObject;
    public CustomGenericOperation(DBObject dbObject){
        this.dbObject = dbObject;

    }
    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(final AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return dbObject;
    }
}
```

## (3) Alternative

Instead of defining a custom AggregationOperation, you could :

- get a random number in Java (assuming you first retrieve the number of documents in the collection)
- In an aggregate query

  - limit(randomNumber)
  - sort ascending
  - limit(1)

In short, limit with a random number and get the last document:

```
$ db.story.aggregate([{$limit: RANDOM_NUMBER},{$sort: {_id: 1}}, {$limit: 1}])
```

Comment: But isn't this a bug? Not being able to use the $sample operator I mean

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug yet.. Just that we don't know how to use at the moment ? :)

Comment: Thanks! Wow! But still isn't it an issue that @Query("{$sample: {size: ?0} }") doesn't work?

Comment: I still think they have something in mind with their Example, it just isn't documented. However, I see few requests for $sample support: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1415  and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1325.  This suggestion that our current solution is the right one as of now!